# GWT 2.4 and google maps

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt

Hi I am building a website in GWT and i can't get google maps to work. I'm using GWT 2.4 and gwt-maps3-0.2b.jar googlemaps. Everytime when i try to use a googlemaps api i get the following exception:

Uncaught exception escaped
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses

I've added the module inherit in my xml and added the jar in my WEB-INF/Lib directory that i added to my build path. Can someone please help me out.

Thank you,

Jan Behang

Full error

> 08:26:23.578 [ERROR] [linkedstarters] Uncaught exception escaped
>
> com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions
>   caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
>       at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:129)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)
>       at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1307)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
>       at com.google.gwt.maps.client.MapOptions.<init>(MapOptions.java:40)
>       at com.linkedstarters.client.pages.Profile.createView(Profile.java:73)
>       at com.linkedstarters.client.pages.Profile.<init>(Profile.java:29)
>       at com.linkedstarters.client.pages.PageFactory.getPage(PageFactory.java:13)
>       at com.linkedstarters.client.handlers.MenuHandler.onClick(MenuHandler.java:28)
>       at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:54)
>       at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:1)
>       at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
>       at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)
>       at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1307)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for
>   'com.google.gwt.maps.client.impl.MapOptionsImpl' (did you forget to
>   inherit a required module?)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
>       at com.google.gwt.maps.client.impl.MapOptionsImpl.<clinit>(MapOptionsImpl.java:31)
>       at com.google.gwt.maps.client.MapOptions.<init>(MapOptions.java:40)
>       at com.linkedstarters.client.pages.Profile.createView(Profile.java:73)
>       at com.linkedstarters.client.pages.Profile.<init>(Profile.java:29)
>       at com.linkedstarters.client.pages.PageFactory.getPage(PageFactory.java:13)
>       at com.linkedstarters.client.handlers.MenuHandler.onClick(MenuHandler.java:28)
>       at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:54)
>       at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:1)
>       at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
>       at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)
>       at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1307)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface
>   com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but class was expected
>       at com.google.gwt.jsio.rebind.JSWrapperGenerator.generate(JSWrapperGenerator.java:276)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generate(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:48)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generateIncrementally(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:60)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:647)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:78)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:268)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ShellModuleSpaceHost.rebind(ShellModuleSpaceHost.java:141)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebind(ModuleSpace.java:585)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:455)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
>       at com.google.gwt.maps.client.impl.MapOptionsImpl.<clinit>(MapOptionsImpl.java:31)
>       at com.google.gwt.maps.client.MapOptions.<init>(MapOptions.java:40)
>       at com.linkedstarters.client.pages.Profile.createView(Profile.java:73)
>       at com.linkedstarters.client.pages.Profile.<init>(Profile.java:29)
>       at com.linkedstarters.client.pages.PageFactory.getPage(PageFactory.java:13)
>       at com.linkedstarters.client.handlers.MenuHandler.onClick(MenuHandler.java:28)
>       at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:54)
>       at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:1)
>       at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
>       at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)
>       at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1307)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Paste more of the stack trace. `UmbrellaException` means there are multiple exceptions caught, each listed with a `Caused by...` block.

Comment: The error seems to happen when you try to create ``MapOptions``:java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null at com.google.gwt.maps.client.MapOptions.<init>(MapOptions.java:40) at 

Can you post some code on how you create your Map object?

Comment: final MapOptions options = new MapOptions();
   options.setZoom(8);
   options.setCenter(new LatLng(model.getUser().getLat(), model.getUser().getLong()));
   options.setMapTypeId(new MapTypeId().getRoadmap());

Comment: I did it just as it said in the example that game with the google maps jar file

Comment: I am having the same problem right now ... ! I get the same error when I create MapOptions object. and here is what I get as an error
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but class was expected 

It seems that GWT.create( .... ) can not create an implementation for the some interface vie deffer binding ... !